# ajax - update listbox in parent form

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I have a form where user can create a player and also associate a team with the it. 
The player form has a select list where user can select an existing team or select the 'new' option which displays a popup which allows user to create a new team and associate it with the player.

I have used javascript to display the popup window when user selects 'new' option.

My new team form is as follows:

```
<% form_remote_tag :url => {:controller => 'players', :action => 'createTeam'} do %>
    <label style="width: 150px">Team name:</label> <%= text_field_tag(:team_name, nil) %>
    <%= submit_tag("Create New Team") %>
<% end %>
```

controller - players, action - createTeam

```
def createTeam
  @team = Team.create(:team_name => params[:team_name])

  respond_to do |format|
  if @team.save
    flash[:notice] = 'Team was successfully created'
    format.html { redirect_to teams_path }
    format.js
  else
    flash[:notice] = "Team failed to save."
    format.html { redirect_to teams_path }
  end

  end
end
```

I would like to be able to update the select list in my parent form (new.html.erb for player) dynamically each time i add a team.

I am a bit confused on how to do this.

I would be grateful if someone could give me an idea on how to go forward.

Many many thanks for any suggestion provided.

Answer (score 0):

You'll need to use something like `replace_html` to re-render the list. [This](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2439327/rails-3-and-rjs) SO question should help you out.