# resource to learn using RJS in Ruby On Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rjs

I try to learn RJS usage in Rails application but I could not find good resource on Web. There are some simple examples but not a vast tutorial that I need. Please suggest any if you know :)

Thanks ...

Comment: What do you want to learn that you aren't?

Answer (score 3):

Doing a Google search, these links seems useful:

- [16 RJS Resources and Tutorials for Rails Programmers](http://www.rubyinside.com/16-rjs-resources-and-tutorials-for-rails-programmers-5.html)
- [Getting Started With RJS in Rails](http://viget.com/extend/getting-started-with-rjs-in-rails)
- [Rails RJS Demo (video)](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=vEky75YBniQ)
- [Rails 3 and RJS (stackoverflow answer)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2439327/rails-3-and-rjs)