# Implementing rjs in php

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ruby-on-rails, ajax

I want to implement a pretty basic [rjs](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10949079/resource-to-learn-using-rjs-in-ruby-on-rails) kind utility in php. For those who have no prior knowledge of it, the rjs utility in Ruby on Rails returns `application\javascript` content-type for ajax requests. This is pretty handy when we want to change the inner html of two different divs through ajax in one request.

So what I need is to read html stream of some *.tpl.php file so that from the server side code, I can return javascript strings as:

```
$rjsStr = "$('#div1').html(".Util::getHtmlFromTpl($outputParams1, 'tplfile1.tpl.php').");";
$rjsStr .= "$('#div2').html(".Util::getHtmlFromTpl($outputParams2, 'tplfile2.tpl.php').");";
return $rjsStr;
```

Now my ajax request would look like `$.ajax({url:'/controller/action.php?param1=1&param2=2',success:function(result){eval(result);}})` 

**Edit** The problem is that I don't know how to get the html stream of php file. I simply tried `include('path_to_file/tplfile1.tpl.php');` but that doesn't return the html stream as a variable. 

**PS:** I don't want to use `file_get_contents` for the security reasons.

Comment: So what is your problem? You said **you** want to implement this util. Then go ahead! BTW since, you're going to evaluate the answer as js code, I'd suggest using `$.getScript`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`include('path_to_file/tplfile1.tpl.php');` includes code and executes it. If you need to just read the file, then you may use `file_get_contents`, but I suppose, you need rendered template as input.

Then you need to use [output buffering](http://www.php.net/manual/en/ref.outcontrol.php).

```
ob_start();
include('path_to_file/tplfile1.tpl.php');
$rendered_tpl = ob_get_clean();
// now you may strip excessive part, escape html and do with it whatever you want
```

Comment: You rock! Looks like this is exactly what I need. Let me check it and get back.